Puzzle pieces snapping anywhere when dropped
So, I'm having this problem build a (what I thought it would be fairly simple) puzzle.
Given a 4x3 grid, and the pieces already separated in 12 different images, I cannot manage to move freely the pieces (I gave up with the snap-in-place validation idea).
Every time I drop the dragged image, it goes to a random place, not where I leave them.
Here's the full code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(PuzzleGridApp());
}

class PuzzleGridApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('ROMPECABEZAS! :D'),
        ),
        body: PuzzleGrid(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PuzzleGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PuzzleGridState createState() => _PuzzleGridState();
}

class _PuzzleGridState extends State<PuzzleGrid> {
  List<Offset> positions = List.generate(12, (index) => const Offset(0, 0));

  final List<Image> puzzlePieces = [
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_0.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_1.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_2.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_3.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_4.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_5.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_6.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_7.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_8.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_9.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_10.png', width: 100, height: 100),
    Image.asset('images/puzzle1_11.png', width: 100, height: 100),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setInitialPositions();
  }

  void setInitialPositions() {
    Random random = Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
      double x = random.nextDouble() * 350; // Random x position
      double y = random.nextDouble() * 250; // Random y position
      positions[i] = Offset(x + 425, y);
    }
  }

  Offset position = const Offset(100, 100);
  double prevScale = 1;
  double scale = 1;

  void updateScale(double zoom) => setState(() => scale = prevScale * zoom);
  void commitScale() => setState(() => prevScale = scale);
  void updatePosition(Offset newPosition) => setState(() => position = newPosition);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
        color: Colors.black54,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onScaleUpdate: (details) => updateScale(details.scale),
          onScaleEnd: (_) => commitScale(),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              // Draw the grid as a background
              CustomPaint(
                size: const Size(400, 300),
                painter: GridPainter(),
              ),
              // Create draggable pieces
              ...List.generate(12, (index) {
                return Positioned(
                  left: positions[index].dx,
                  top: positions[index].dy,
                  child: Draggable<int>(
                    maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
                    data: index,
                    feedback: puzzlePieces[index],
                    childWhenDragging: Container(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    onDragEnd: (details) => updatePosition(details.offset),
                    child: Transform.scale(
                      scale: scale,
                      child: puzzlePieces[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// CustomPainter class to draw the grid
class GridPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    double cellWidth = size.width / 4;
    double cellHeight = size.height / 3;

    // Draw vertical lines
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(cellWidth * i, 0),
        Offset(cellWidth * i, size.height),
        paint,
      );
    }

    // Draw horizontal lines
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(0, cellHeight * i),
        Offset(size.width, cellHeight * i),
        paint,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

I've already tried without any kind of validation in order to at least make it manually. No luck.
This is a puzzle that's needed to run on an Android TV for people to play. I'll add the reset button later.

Here's a video of the behavior that I'm having right now:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/HDou32JGb7AFzMAZ8

maybe this would help: https://gist.github.com/pskink/468b0ed8859a85f94f0040c552e3a488 - this is the first, the simplest revision: https://gist.github.com/pskink/468b0ed8859a85f94f0040c552e3a488/1998de8c6a5ea14478faccfb270ce248ebb00d70

This was actually very much helpfull! Thank you a lot!
I cannot find the button for a thumbs up tho

sure, your welcome
